# How to format a string being sent with google voice to have a new line

Tags: python, string, voice

I am using googlevoice and python to send a message through texting but '\n' does not get read in as a new line when sending the text with the googlevoice api. is there specific string formatting to get this right?

```
final_message = "Thank you for using our automated SMS system. Your schedule is: "\
+ schedule_message

voice.send_sms(received_phone, final_message)
```

I would like a new line before "Your schedule is:"

edit : for those of you who want to know what I've tried:

```
final_message = "Thank you for using our automated SMS system. \nYour schedule is: "\
+ schedule_message

voice.send_sms(received_phone, final_message)
```

and

```
final_message = "Thank you for using our automated SMS system. \r\n Your schedule is: "\
+ schedule_message

voice.send_sms(received_phone, final_message)
```

and

```
final_message = "Thank you for using our automated SMS system.  %0a Your schedule is:"\
+ schedule_message

voice.send_sms(received_phone, final_message)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @be_good_do_good I posted what I can

Comment: No, there's no _'special string formatting'_ for that. Normally, a new line is `\n` for UNIX and `\r\n` for Windows.

Comment: @ForceBru neither \r\n nor \n are read in as new lines with this, that is my error